# how to defer resolve tasks in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am new to nodejs, recently I am not sure how to arrange tasks in order such that they behave correctly.

below are two examples

```
arr.forEach(function(elem){
    //do many many things
});
console.log('done, now take ur pick');
stdin.on('input', function action(){
    ...
})
```

how can I set stdin.on fire after arr.forEach.
and question 2 I think if I do

```
fn1();
fn2();

function fn1(){
    //long long code
}

function fn2(){
    console.log('fn2 is done!')
}
```

and runs the above, the execution will be in a thread of

fn1 fn2 fn1 fn1 fn1, right? how to prevent this?

Comment: You *are* listening to `input` events on the `stdin` only after the `forEach` loop has ended. Since your question is about asynchronous behaviour, you will need to show us *what* asynchronous functions you actually do call. Please post the relevant sections of the `many many things` and the `long long code`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in node.js are either synchronous or asynchronous. Synchronous code runs in a single thread, and behaves exactly like the code you're used to:

```
fn1();
fn2();
fn3(fn4());
```

Will run `fn1`, then `fn2`, then `fn4`, then `fn3` (passing in the result of `fn4` as a parameter).

Asynchronous code fires off some action, and takes as a parameter the function to execute when it's done (which might, in turn, fire off another asynchronous action). You get control back immediately. Example:

```
doSomeAsyncThing(function () {
    console.log("did the async thing");
});
console.log("hello");
```

executes like this: First, the asynchronous action is fired off, then "hello" is printed. Some time later, the asynchronous action completes, so the callback is called, and "did the async thing" is printed.

If you want to do one asynchronous thing, then do another asynchronous thing after the first one is finished, the standard way to is nest the callbacks:

```
async1(function() {
    async2(function() {
        console.log("async1 and async2 finished");
    });
});
```

Although [there](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) are [better](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird) options.

So in your second example, if `fn1` is synchronous, it will work perfectly exactly as you wrote it. If `fn1` has to do something asynchronous, it too will have to be asynchronous, so you will have to write it like this:

```
function fn1(callback) {
    // do some sync stuff
    doSomethingAsync(function () {
        // do more sync stuff
        doSomethingMoreAsync(function () {
            // do more sync stuff
            callback(); // call the callback once everything is completed
        });
    });
}
```

And then call it like this

```
fn1(function () {
    fn2();
});
```

Which could be simplified to:

```
fn1(fn2);
```

In your first example, note that array.forEach is synchronous. If your `// do many many things` are all synchronous, then that will work exactly as you wrote it, but if there's an asynchronous action in there, you can either manually implement a counter, or just use the [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) library or [Promise iterator utilities](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#collections).

Comment: great explantion, but what is the difference between async1(fn->async2(fn)) vs. fn1(fn2)? aren't they the same way of implementing the same idea of callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

by adding the stdin to the callback function of the forEach function. Like:

```
arr.forEach(function(elem){
    //do many many things
}, function() {
    console.log('done, now take ur pick');
    stdin.on('input', function action(){
        ...
    });
});
```

Using this, the stdin and console.log functions will be called only after completion of the forEach loop.

Comment: so in general, callback will always be needed if i want to execute two functions in order? such I pass in fn2 to fn1?

Comment: yeah. Because of the non-blocking property, function2 will be executed immediately after function1 has started executing and would not wait for function1 to finish.

Comment: i tried it and now stdin.on is never fired and program ends

Comment: `forEach` does not have a (second, "finished") callback, or is `arr` not an Array?

Comment: And regarding the forEach callback, I'm sorry for that. The callback is for errors and not completion.
forEach(function(), function(err));